# phpmyadmin is not importing the constraints of database

Tags: database, constraints

i m importing an sql which has constraints defined in it but when i import it in the phpmyadmin it does not sets the constraints because when i export the database there is no constraints defined....

what may b possibly wrong any idea???

Answer (score 0):

Check the importing database engine. It has to be InnoDB to accept constraints. My guess is that you have MyISAM.